# Neutab air 7 stuck on fastboot mode

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

Neutab air 7 stuck on fastboot mode
Brand new a week out of the box
Will not power down or respond...... any ideas/suggestions???

[image]

Comment: Get a replacement where you've bought it? Within the first week, that's well inside the warranty frame. Apart from that: What did you do to bring it into that state – I mean, apart from unboxing? It probably didn't ship in the current state :) As the picture is too small, it might also help to [edit] your question to include what's written on the screen (cannot be read from the picture).

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 options I can see, select Boot normally. Use Volume down to navigate and choose with Volume Up button. If not succeed, select Recovery boot and reset your tablet